# iOS Navigation with side menu

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I need to create a navigation in iOS app like following screenshot.

[image]

It contains a Tab Bar and a Side menu.

The problem is the right navigation menu button, should be visible in all tabs. Even all inner screens of each tab.

When user selects an option from side menu, it should be displayed on screen.

Now each tab should be accessible from each option item, and each option menu should be accessible in each tab. Its like a many-to-many relationship in DB.

How should I design it?

I have tried following so far.

1. Within each tab, there is a `containerViewController`. Which consists of my `FrontViewController` and `SideMenuViewController`.
2. When an option is selected from side menu, a message is passed to `containerViewController` which removes the old `FrontViewController` from view and adds new `OptionViewController`.
3. The menu button and navigation bar is added in `containerViewController`, so that if should be visible every time, at any screen.

**Problems**

Now facing some problems using this approach.

1. As the navigation bar is added in `containerViewController`. I have access it using `parent` property of my `FrontViewController`. Suppose if I need to use `PushViewController` in my `FrontViewController`, I have to use `parent` property. Like this

   `[self.parent.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES ];`
   `[self.parent.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`
2. I have to use this approach within each tab. Means code is repeating 5 times.

Can anyone suggest a simple solution. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [InteractiveSideMenu](https://github.com/handsomecode/InteractiveSideMenu) for your purpose. It supports interactive opening/closing menu and following customization:

- Animation duration
- Visible content width
- Content scale
- Using spring animation with params customization
- Animation options like animation curve

You should use 3 basic ViewControllers for creating subclasses for implementing your side menu.

- `MenuContainerViewController` is a host for menu and content views
- `MenuViewController` is a container for menu view
- `MenuItemContentControlller` is a container for content that corresponds menu item

Here is an example of setup Host controller.

```
import InteractiveSideMenu

class HostViewController: MenuContainerViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.menuViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationMenu") as! MenuViewController

        self.contentViewControllers = contentControllers()

        self.selectContentViewController(contentViewControllers.first!)
    }

    private func contentControllers() -> [MenuItemContentViewController] {
        //here is instantiation of content view controllers
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would think about subclassing `UINavigationController` and adding your button management logic there. When any view controller is pushed into the nav controller, set its bar button item.

The side menu shouldn't be inside each tab. Your root view controller should really control the main and side views and the main view has your tab controller which has a navigations controller as the root of each tab.

Now that the navigation bar doesn't need to be managed by a different container controller things become easier.

Bar button actions push up to the root view controller only, a reference to it can be set when the navigation controllers are created. Option selection would traverse root VC -> main (tab) VC -> selected tab nav controller -> push.

Answer (score -1):

It could be easier to use a cocoapod for iOS side menus such as  [APMultiMenu](https://github.com/aadeshp/APMultiMenu). I've used it and it's simple to use and follow

Comment: Please don't give link-only answers. Links can break at any time